# project doesn't print the results

Tags: c

when i run the program I enter a value for n and the program ends whys is that?

```
//fahrenheit values for celcius degrees between 0-n
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n; double c=0, f;
    printf("n:"); scanf("%d", n);
    while(c<=n)
    {
        f=(9*c+160)/5;
        printf("%f celcius = %f fahrenhayt \n", c, f);
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i was expecting the program to print the values from 0-n line by line but after entering the value program just ends

Comment: what value do you enter?

Comment: In your scanf statement, you should be using "&n" and not n.

Comment: ```scanf``` requires a pointer as it's second argument. Change ```scanf("%d", n);``` to ```scanf("%d", &n);```

Comment: ive entered 100 and 10

Comment: forgot about & thanks a bunch

Comment: Turn all compiler warnings on, it will save much of your time.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to provide the address of `n` to `scanf` by adding `&` in front of the `n`:

`scanf("%d", &n);`

Try again. Here is the code corrected.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n; double c=0, f;
    printf("n:"); scanf("%d", &n);
    while(c <= n) {
        f = (9 * c + 160) / 5;
        printf("%f celcius = %f fahrenhayt \n", c, f);
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, `double` is an odd type to use for `c` if it's meant to increment up by 1.  If it's typed that way to make the math work, it might be better to make it an `int` but use `(9.0 * c + 160.0) / 5` or even better:  `1.8 * c + 32.0`. Additionally, the while loop can be a for loop:  `for (int c = 0; c <= n; c++) { ... }`

Comment: Well, I didn't want to change the original code much. I only added the piece that was failing and put the code here so its easier to copy and paste for the author of the question

Comment: Even simpler, `for(int c = 0, double f = 32.0; c <= n; c++, f += 1.8)`.

Comment: @Neil that's a nice code you put there; however, remember that the author of the original question maybe learning how to code in C. I would advice to include an explanation for him.